# How to find the wrong reference dll in website when debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

All, I am stuck in a problem which drive me crazy... please help to review it . thanks in advance.

I want to reference a `NHibernate.dll` to my website with the version number `2.1.0.4000`.
But I didn't know why the website always to search the `NHibernate.dll` of version number `2.1.2.4000` when I try to debug it.

[image]

Here is what I try to do .

1. try to use `fuslogvw` to trace the assembly binding .

[image]
you can see the application want to bind the `2.1.2.4000` which is not my desired version.

2. remove all the reference of `Nhibernate` in my solution. and add the right one again.
3. To the website project. I found the dll I just added show `auto update` in the version number column instead of the right version number in the reference dialog. I don't why.

[image]

Could someone please help to give me some idea to figure out what happened to it . thanks. any comments are welcome.

**updated**

I searched with key text "NHibernate" in the `Web.Config`

the content about it is below.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Iesi.Collections" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.3" newVersion="1.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.1.4000" newVersion="2.1.0.4000"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" processorArchitecture="amd64"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.102.4.0" newVersion="2.112.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" processorArchitecture="ia64"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.102.4.0" newVersion="2.112.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**updated**

I checked dll in the `Reflector`, Anything wrong with it ?

[image]

**Updated**

The manifast of ILdasm shows below
[image]

**Updated**

Sometimes I found the log shows some clue which assembly reference the wrong dll.
you can see "Calling assembly: xxxx.dll, version=........."

Comment: I m not sure but I think problem is on your web.config file not about dll's

Comment: And I want to know which dll reference this wrong dll. How has it been loaded.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its an issue with your `dll` file itself. The manifest of the `.dll` file has declared the version details in a wrong way. Try to download another copy of the file from some other resource. Now clean your solution, add a reference to it and rebuild the solution. The error should go.

Comment: Alternatively, you can edit the manifest of the `.dll` file using a Hex Editor and change the version details.

Comment: You can see the dll has been binded twice . one of them is wrong version. please check the trace log above. thanks. I just can't understand why bind twice.

Comment: The two binding you can see is basically two different part of the same dll. There is a mismatch in the version of this two part.

Comment: I check the dll with reflector , the version is 2.1.0.4000. it is right number.please review my updated . thanks. I didn't know what you mean manifest. how can I inspect it ?

Comment: Use IL Disassembler from Windows SDK Tools. There you can view the methods and classes exposed by the DLL file. You will also find a manifest on the top. Kindly check there. If the creator of the DLL has used ILMerge to club multiple DLL files, then the situation may be more complicated.

Comment: What I guessed is purely based on the error message showed on your first screenshot. Do you have any particular Error Code???

Comment: This may give you some useful insight.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I just check the Manifest of some dll files with ILdasm in my machine. found some clue. the above manifest screenshot is the `NHibernate.validator` . It looks like the dll reference the dll Nhibernate 2.1.2.4000, right ?

Comment: You got to the right place. Instead of fixing it, download another copy or another version of the DLL from sourceforge.net and reference the new one.

Comment: You show me one of the right direction to go . great!